# clicking the debug button in Eclipse will not start debug mode

Tags: android, debugging

i am running Eclipse 3.5.0 on a MacBook Pro using the Android SDK. i noticed that on this particular project i am working on i cant seem to actually enter debug mode. i click the little green bug icon in the tool bar and the app starts and runs. but if i switch over to the Debug Perspective i see no indication that it is running in debug mode. furthermore i can not hit any brake points that i have set. this makes debugging code a bit hard. Other projects that i am working on don't have this issue. any ideas on what i need to change in the project to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set debugable to true in the project's manifest.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, and Google recommends against setting debuggable. See http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html, the SDK Tools, Revision 8 (December 2010) section.

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking (or control-clicking) on the project name and select Debug As Android Application